# Why isn't the SQLiteOpenHelper called just SQLiteHelper?

Tags: android, naming-conventions

The documentation describes the class as a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. Having that in mind wouldn't you say that the name is a little misleading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling it SQLiteHelper would be more misleading as this might encourage people to write their queries and data manipulation inside this class. This classes primary role is db creation, upgrading and opening.

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't help you to do EVERYTHING with database (as SQLiteHelper supposed to do). It helps only to open/manage database connection.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html